# How to make image row of different size images same by height and fill all window width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I having a gallery on my website where all images equal by width but different by height.

[My website link](https://mas-tak.com/Portfolio/Portfolio?creator=Nixeu)

I would like to make them to scale with same height and full all width.

[image: my gallery with different height]

Comment: You should try giving them percentage widths, this way they wil always keep their size depending on the page. For example `width: 20%;`  Let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Just add the following CSS: `img {height: [size here]}` and that will force the height to be what you want all images to be and then the widths will scale to stay in proportion.

Comment: @RomeoBeun How will setting the `width` help solve the OP's question about image height? (It won't.)

Comment: Thank you both,  if I give them `width: 20%`  the height will be different,
and if I  give them same height they will not cover all window width.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I need to give all images same height, but how I calculate which one to make they full width same as window. No bigger no less.

Comment: If you set the height, the width will scale automatically so that the image proportions will stay correct. If you set the height and then set the width, the image will be skewed. The only solution for what you want is to resize the images to the exact sizes you want using image software  and then bring them into your web page.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You are right my bad for reading wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this ( [How to create a responsive image gallery with CSS flexbox](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-create-responsive-image-gallery-css-flexbox/) ) blog, it will give you exactly what you want. It shows how to make a responsive image gallery using css flexbox.

Definition of
`flex-grow` property (w3schools), specifies how much a flex item will grow relative to the rest of the flex items.

Definition of
`flex-shrink` property (w3schools), specifies how much a flex item will shrink relative to the rest of the flex items.

Definition of
`flex-basis` property (w3schools), specifies the initial length of a flex item.

Definition of
`object-fit` property (w3schools), specify how an  or  should be resized to fit its container.

Below code is taken from the link provided above.

```css
.image-gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.image-gallery > li {
  height: 300px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;  /* shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}

.image-gallery li img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="image-gallery">
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1541411438265-4cb4687110f2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8aGQlMjBwaG90b3N8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503249023995-51b0f3778ccf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGQlMjBwaG90b3N8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444703686981-a3abbc4d4fe3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBwaG90b3N8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614160859544-177611d11f6b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8aGQlMjBwaG90b3N8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" />
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500462918059-b1a0cb512f1d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8aGQlMjBwaG90b3N8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597283712405-819a6021326c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fGhkJTIwcGhvdG9zfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571348264903-c3af9582e4ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fGhkJTIwcGhvdG9zfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550041771-aef92f14a6d5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTd8fGhkJTIwcGhvdG9zfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601314167099-232775b3d6fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fGhkJTIwcGhvdG9zfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a div under the main div and set all images as a background image. and apply the same height to col-div(Child div) through CSS and background CSS property.

For Example as per your site reference :

```html
<div id="pictures_gallery">
  <div class="col-div" style="background-image:url('your image path here');"></div>
  <div class="col-div" style="background-image:url('your image path here');"></div>
</div>
```